# how to start another task once async call is completed

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

Currently, I am using firebase. I populate my table using firebase async call `observeEventType`. However now I am also using `BTNavigationDropdownMenu` and I would need to populate my title from the database. As firebase query is async, how can I make it such that only when it is completed then `BTNavigationDropdownMenu` will be fired?

This is the call I make at `viewDidAppear` to retrieve data from firebase

```
_ = dataRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshotOne) in

        self.titleList.insert("\(snapshotOne.key)", atIndex: 0)
})
```

This is supposed to fire after data is retrieved

```
let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController, title: titleList.first!, items: titleList)

self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView
```

The error that I am getting is `unwrapping a nil in titleList`, which of course is the case since `titleList` has not been populated by firebase.

I tried 2 things which failed. Firstly, I placed the `BTNavigationDropdownMenu` codes in my firebase call. But that gave me a memory warning as the codes kept being called.

Secondly I tried using `dispatch_async` and `serial queue` but it didnt work since I was queueing a async code within an async code, which means my queue fired the firebase async codes and moved to my `BTNavigationDropdownMenu` before firebase responded.

Comment: What kind of data is being retrieved? i.e. The .Value call retrieves everything within the node at dataRef. Is it just one string or a series of child nodes? The answer may be super simple but it depends on what's in snapshotOne.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the titleView inside the async completion closure of value event

```
 dataRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshotOne) in

        self.titleList.insert("\(snapshotOne.key)", atIndex: 0)
        let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController, title: titleList.first!, items: titleList)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView
})
```

Comment: how can I deallocate it or something then? because my firebase call is under `viewDidAppear` and everytime I go back to the view, my memory usage keeps increasing. that happens only when `BTNavigationDropdownMenu` is inside the firebase call

Comment: try setting `self.navigationItem.titleView = nil` in `viewDidDisappear` then

Comment: It didnt work, so I tried commenting `self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView` away and it seems that the `let menuView = ...` is the one causing the memory usage increase. What should I do. Is it because I need to make it have a weak reference?

Comment: i would instead try to find if i can update the menu items list explicitly rather then initializing it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to subclass `UINavigationController` to solve your memory problems. The `menuView` is getting initialized within `UIViewController` but then added as a `subview` of `navigationController`. So when the `ViewController` should dealloc, The `menuView` hasn't dealloc'd because its still on the `navigationController`, while still having a reference to `UIViewController` so your `UIViewController` cannot dealloc either. Its not on the navigationStack, but still exists in memory creating your issue. Here is a quick subclass.

```
class MyNavController : UINavigationController {
   var menuView : BTNavigationDropdownMenu = BTNavigationDropdownMenu()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      //Do additional setup like adding to superView or whatever else you need. 
      titleView = menuView
   }
}
```

In firebase completion block

```
_ = dataRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshotOne) in
        //Individually set all of the values of your menuView here.
       if let navVC = self.navigationController as? MyNavController {
           navVC.menuView.title = titleList.first 
       }

})
```

The key here is that menuView now only has a reference to the navBar so will deallocate itself with the navBar and your VC can now dealloc on its since menuView no longer has a reference to it. So while creating weak reference could solve your memory issues, It makes more sense for the life-cycle of menuView to follow the life cycle of your `navController` if it lives on the `navController`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try it and let you know later!

Comment: I understand what you are trying to explain and thank you for that. however, I am not very experienced and i do have some troubles with the execution. `if let navVC = self.navigationController as? MyNavController` is not firing up. I tried putting a `print` inside and it isn't printing anything